# how do we right align part of a line in r markdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am working on an R markdown document and was trying to see if we can right align the end of a sentence.

The sentence should look like :

This is the same sentence's first part <*spacespacespace space space*>         this is the end of sentence.

I have tried comibining LaTeX syntax with it

This is the same sentence's first part

```
\begin{flushright}
sample end of sentence
\end{flushright}
```

But this doesnt give the desired effect.

Can someone please help?

Comment: What output format are you using? Most LaTeX commands should work if you are outputting to PDF, but you'll need a different solution for HTML or other formats.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**PDF document**
Use `LaTeX` `\hfill` command:

```
This is the same sentence's first part \hfill this is the end of sentence.
```

**HTML document**
Use `CSS` `float` property.
Since Pandoc 1.18, you can create a native `span` with [`bracketed_spans`](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-bracketed_spans)

```
This is the same sentence's first part [this is the end of sentence.]{style="float:right"}
```

**Both PDF & HTML?**
You can use both `LaTeX` `\hfill` and a `HTML` floating span (be careful, use a no-break-space between `\hfill` and `[this`):

```
This is the same sentence's first part \hfill [this is the end of sentence.]{style="float:right"}
```

---

#### PDF result

[image]

#### HTML result

```html
<p><strong>PDF document</strong><br />
Use <code>LaTeX</code> <code>\hfill</code> command:</p>
<p>This is the same sentence’s first part this is the end of sentence.</p>
<p><strong>HTML document</strong><br />
Use <code>CSS</code> <code>float</code> property.<br />
Since Pandoc 1.18, you can create a native <code>span</code> with <a href="https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-bracketed_spans"><code>bracketed_spans</code></a></p>
<p>This is the same sentence’s first part <span style="float:right;">this is the end of sentence.</span></p>
<p><strong>Both PDF &amp; HTML?</strong><br />
You can use both <code>LaTeX</code> <code>\hfill</code> and a <code>HTML</code> floating span (be careful, use a no-break-space between <code>\hfill</code> and <code>[this</code>):</p>
<p>This is the same sentence’s first part  <span style="float:right;">this is the end of sentence.</span></p>
```